# Socket sniffer python only sniff port 22

Tags: python, sockets, packet-sniffers, raw-sockets

I am programming a sniffer in python with sockets and I am not sure why I only sniff on the port 22.
I am in a machine connected via ssh from ip 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.3 and when I sniff I only sniff the ssh traffic, I am trying this for sniffing non port 22 traffic:

```
import socket
from struct import *

print 'Bienvenido'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65000)
    packet = packet[0]
    ip_header = packet[0:20]
    iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

    ip_src = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8])
    ip_dst = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9])

    tcp_header = packet[20:40]
    tcp_h = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH',tcp_header)
    src_port = tcp_h[0]
    dst_port = tcp_h[1]
    if str(dst_port)!="22":
        print 'ip_src : ' + ip_src
        print 'ip dst : ' + ip_dst
        print 'src port: ' + str(src_port)
        print 'dst port: ' + str(dst_port)
```

But I don't sniff anything, if I change into `if str(dst_port)!="22":` I sniff the traffic from 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.3.
On the remote machine I have started tcpdump sniffing on the port 80, connected to google via telnet to the port 80, I have also tried with FTP traffic but no success, and I sniff in tcpdump but not on my sniffer. Does anyone what is maybe happening¿?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you should use `scapy` for this  kind of work

Comment: Are you sure that you are generating some non SSH traffic too. Run wireshark and check the sniffed network traffic, if it contains any non SSH traffic or not.

Comment: Yes as I said I captured with tcpdump on eth0 and I captured other kind of traffic, in fact, I run tcpdump and my sniffer at the same time, opened a telnet to google on the port 80, tcpdump sniffed and my sniffer didn't

Comment: @Micheled'Amico scapy does not sniff ssh packet on remote computer. I have tried it but no result. here is my post <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141691/scapy-ssh-connection-my-network-sniffing-from-my-router>