# ssh packets sniffing from my router with scapy

Tags: python, security, networking, ssh, scapy

I want to sniff ssh connection to  any pc on my network. I have scapy on my router and I would like to get a sniff result whenever someone connect to any of my pc in my network using ssh. This what I did by I have no result.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *

def sniffSSHRequest():
    sniff(iface='eth0', filter="tcp and host 192.168.1.2 and port 22", count=1)

 sniffSSHRequest()
```

Note that all my pc can ping the router and they can also ping each other. The question is why don't I get a sniff.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww Thanks for your comment but I don't understand what you mean very well, because I have the intuition that my question is not about programming. Which is not true at all, this is a python code. sniff is scapy library maybe I should add the entire code.

Comment: I added the entire python code

Comment: How do you intend to read encrypted data in the tunnels?

Comment: @RonMaupin  I just want to get anything from ssh packets. That will be a big stage. the encryption is another stage. Even if scapy could tell me that there was a connection through port 22 from some where, that will already be a some ssh sniff for me. but apparently it is just doing nothing.

Comment: If the router does NAT, you could look at the NAT table to see your inside hosts that have those connections.

Comment: @RonMaupin The main project is about proof concept. the router is a VM just doing some ip fowarding. pcapy is for instance capturing the ssh packets. Scapy unfortunatly is not doing it. And from their documentation the syntax looks correct but from my experience it not doing really the sniffing that well. I don't know if you get my point?